# Alfresco Mobile: Kerberos und iOS login: java.io.IOException: ASN.1 type 0x3a decode not supported

Tags: alfresco, kerberos, asn.1

In my Alfresco installation (5.0.d Community), I have the following authentication chain:

```
authentication.chain=kerberos1:kerberos,ldap1:ldap,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm
```

I can login with any desktop browser as well as with the Alfresco mobile app for **Android just fine**, both on port 8080 (http) and port 443 (https).

But when I try to login with **iPhone or iPad**, I am getting the following **error** message in the log (both http and https):

```
[org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.KerberosAuthenticationFilter] 
[http-bio-443-exec-13] java.io.IOException: ASN.1 type 0x3a decode not supported

[org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.KerberosAuthenticationFilter] 
[http-bio-8080-exec-6] java.io.IOException: ASN.1 type 0x3a decode not supported
```

Does anybody have an idea what the problem is here or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several candiates as root cause.

- I assume you have enabled sso? Alfresco doesn't support fallback to basic auth on several protocols (yet) if SSO is enabled: https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ACE-2678
  As for now you need to set `kerberos.authentication.sso.enabled=false`
  to get iOS running.
- Additionally you need to set the proxy parameters in the tomcat connector or configure a RemoteIpValve if tomcat is not your endpoint.
- If connecting thru https iOS requires trusted ssl certs. The easiest way to accomplish that is to use nginx or apache as reverse proxy

Comment: One approach could be to enable your iOS device for kerberos auth. I found an article describing that and I'm courious if this is also working with Alfresco's JAAS implementation: https://samuelyates.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/kerberos-single-sign-on-in-ios-7/

Comment: Thanks for that hint, Heiko. Didn't know that. (ACE-2678)